# How to say that a movement is not linear

Tags: word-choice

We know that growth is not linear. We won't reach the target in a straight-forward path. We move phase-by-phase.

Now I'm looking for a word to describe it. 
The growth is not linear, it's... (What)?

Comment: *Non-linear growth* is quite popular phrase.

Comment: @MaulikV Is there a positive word instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider *sporadic*:

> happening only occasionally or at intervals that are not regular - [***OALD***](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sporadic)

Comment: Searching "sporadic" in google images showed me that `sporadic` would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The growth is not linear.

The adjective *linear*, as you identified here, means the growth does not happen straightaway. It involves many things and hence, we achieve it gradually, steadily and phase-by-phase.

Non-linear growth is quite popular and generally used in the language. I **strongly recommend that** but since you are particular about using a positive/single word, **one of the options** could be -

> The growth is not linear, it's *piecemeal.* - This word is the [closest](http://thesaurus.com/browse/step-by-step) to something happening *step-by-step.*

The origin as stated [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/piecemeal?q=piecemeal) -

> Middle English: from the noun piece + -meal from Old English mǣlum, in the sense 'measure, quantity **taken at one time**'.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider *erratic*:

> acting, moving, or changing in ways that are not expected or usual : not consistent or regular

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erratic

Answer (score 0):

I don't think my dialect of American English has such a word, I think "growth happens in stages" might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a word which can describe this context.